# Icons missing from gnome notification panel after an unlock

Tags: gnome, icons, notification-area

focus your eyes on the notification panel.

This is the screenshot before locking my PC.(See the notification panel)
[image: Notification Panel]

And this is the notification panel that I get after unlocking. I am getting this problem since I installed Gnome 3.36. As you can see, some icons are missing but it becomes Ok after I manually restart the computer.

[image: after unlock]
**How to fix it.......**

Comment: What happens if you change the theme?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity it's not a theme problem, I have changed 100s of themes but it remains the same always.